# what are hidden files ending with ~?

Tags: backup

I noticed while working on my site through nano/terminal that ubuntu creates weird ~ files.

I've index.php~ etc.

I imagine this are backup files? is this correct? why does it do this? and how do I get rid of this functionality?

Comment: And related, if you already have a bunch of those backup files laying around and want to remove them all automatically from the terminal, see [How do I remove hidden backup files?](http://askubuntu.com/q/317134/23496)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, those are backup files, most Unix editors do that. You can disable them with:

```
unset backup
```

in your `~/.nanorc`. See `man nanorc` for more information.

Comment: This will only deactivate it for the nano editor.. Don't be surprised if files with that ending will still be created - by other applications.

Comment: so how do I disable it systemwide?

Comment: Why do you want to disable it systemwide? It seems like a good practice to me.

Comment: it doesn't function correctly anyways. Right now index.php~ and index.php have same content - even though I edited out the main file.

Answer (score 0):

If you use GEdit (Ubuntu's default *non-terminal* text editor, and usually just shows up as named *Text Editor*), by default it also creates such backup files. To disable them, open the `Tools > Preferences` menu, switch to the `Editor` tab, and uncheck the *"Create a backup copy of files before saving"* checkbox.