# How do I remove hidden backup files?

Tags: backup, gedit, hidden-files, nano

I have files ending in ~ in my home directory, and I want to delete them. How do I do that? How do I prevent this backup functionality?

Comment: I hope you don't have cause to regret preventing backup functionality!

Comment: No, I already have other ways to backup my work, but I just think that this kind of backup is meaningless. I prefer external copies or the cloud.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply run `rm *~` if you're sure there is no other file that you need which ends in `~`

If it is `gedit` that is creating the backup files, you can open gedit and select `Edit->Preferences->Editor` and uncheck the option `"Create a backup copy of files before saving"`

And for `nano`, look in `/etc/nanorc` for:

```
## Backup files to filename~.
set backup
```

and change that to

```
## Backup files to filename~.
# set backup
```

Comment: I already removed nano anyway. Is there a way of removing gedit without breaking the kernel?

Comment: just do "sudo apt-get remove gedit". Btw, Do you have another editor installed?

Comment: Yes, I have Vim; I just wanted to try out gedit.

Comment: You may like to have a look at this. http://askubuntu.com/questions/97683/how-can-i-change-the-default-text-editor-from-gedit-to-vim

Comment: It's not working for me.

Comment: Aren't you getting Vim in the Open with list? Right click on a file and choose open with other application.

Comment: No, I still have gedit. The only thing that seems to happen is that when I search for via dash, Vim has its own icon now which is blank.

Answer (score 13):

If you also have unwanted backup files in subfolders, it gets a bit more difficult:

```
find . -type f -name '*~' -delete
```

Answer (score -2):

The hidden files are in place to keep user program setup and other program information.

I strongly suggest you to not delete those files.

If you a sure to want to delete them, then open the menu
Places->Home Folder (press CTRL+H if you don't see hidden files)
and then select and press the Delete keyboard key.
If you don't want move them into trash press Shift+Delete keyboard keys

From terminal you can delete hidden files ( don't do it ) with:
rm -fr /home/youruser/.*

Comment: Those are the hidden files that I am not looking for.

Comment: You can use that do delete the files though.