# Why are there files ending with ~ on my system?

Tags: hidden-files

Ive got Ubuntu desktop up and running on my N54L microserver. I've noticed however that if I'm looking at a folder on the microserver from my Windows 7 laptop, if I make a change to a file on Ubuntu and save the file, on Windows it creates a copy (or a reference) of the file but with a ~ on the end.

I can't see it on Ubuntu, only on Windows, and if I delete the original file, the ~ file remains. I can delete the ~ file at any time; it doesn't seem to make any difference to the actual file. Can anyone enlighten me as to what's going on?

Comment: These are backup files created by editors (`nano`, `gedit`, etc). See http://askubuntu.com/questions/317134/how-do-i-remove-hidden-backup-files

Comment: You *can* see them on ubuntu. Just "show hidden files". Since Ubuntu knows that they are backup it doesn't litter the file list with duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

I know for a fact that Vim always creates a backup ending in ~ for any file you edit as default behavior. Whatever editor you're using is likely doing something similar.