# Why does deleted files also appear in directory

Tags: files, directory, root

For example consider that i have created a file temp.txt
and delete it later, there is still an invisible file temp.txt~
Of course I can delete it but Why do i need to do it always,
So how to avoid it..

Comment: ~ files are backup files created by editors like gEdit. See the preferences of the program you made the file with. SEE: http://askubuntu.com/questions/317134/how-do-i-remove-hidden-backup-files

Answer (score 1):

The file with tilde is called *backup file* and made everytime you edited a file on an editor. If you want, you can recover the file from that backup. Otherwise, delete it also.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want it, open Gedit and go to Edit->Preferences->Editor and uncheck Create Backup Copy if it's checked. 

Also you can open terminal and navigate to that dir then

```
rm *.ext~
```