# search for files and delete from the whole system file

Tags: command-line

search for files and delete from the whole system file

If you create a file or just open a file with some programs like gedit, it will make auto save files named like this `file~`. For example if i do this **`gedit file.txt`** then when i close the file i can find two files **`file.txt`** and **`file.txt~`**.

What i want to do is to search the "`/`" whole file system for these files and then delete them.
Note that those files could be other things not just text files.Thanks foe helping

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I remove hidden backup files?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/317134/how-do-i-remove-hidden-backup-files)

Comment: It's not duplicate i want to delete in the whole system not in a single place

Comment: for that you'd use `sudo find / ... ...` [not recommended] to adapt the [answer in the link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/317134/how-do-i-remove-hidden-backup-files) to suit your need.. but I don't think you need to do this, the system config file-backups won't take much space, and they could prove useful.. instead you can just do this for user-home directories `find $HOME ... ...`

Comment: **Do not delete in the whole system!** The filesystem is managed by Ubuntu itself and if you try collect garbage that way you may end up with broken system!

Comment: Why i should not do it for the whole system?!! how could it be end with broken system?

Answer (score 1):

To delete all backup files ending in `~` from the whole system, you can use:

```
sudo find / -type f -name '*~' -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Warning: I suggest you to run first `find / -type f -name '*~'` to see exactly what you will delete.

Comment: This will not work if there is an extension. Am i right? since *~ will not include files that has more than something like *~.txt

Comment: `*~.txt` ?!?! Doesn't exists such kind of backup files AFAIK. Only if you created manually. It's about `*.txt~` and *yes*, my answer will work for these files, too.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu what about using `-ok` instead of `-exec`? With `-ok`, the deletion will be interactive. Please comment!

Comment: @DKBose OK; also you can use `rm -i` instead of `rm -f` for the same purpose.